# Where is learn_runner documented in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Seeing examples I can verify that this import works ok:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_runner
```

However, no proper documentation seems to be provided in the documentation of `r1.1` for  Tensorflow version `v1.1`. Where can I find details about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a documented [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9032) on the Tensorflow Github.

Basically they say (martinwicke from TF on 6 Apr, 2017)

> We will add documentation shortly as we move this utility from contrib to core. This should happen within the next month or so.
>
> Note that this is still in contrib and its interface may still change.

That being said two months ago from the moment of this answer's post. Meawhile, you can check the source code of `learn_runner` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_runner.py) and try to understand more of it from the comments added, seems to be the best you can do right now.

Cheers